# nested dropdown list in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to implement nested `dropdown` list into my GUI, so what I need to add more is like when I click on `option1` it should open again another `dropdown` list.

Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Windows:
   def __init__(self,master):
        var = tk.StringVar()
        optionMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(master,var,'Default')
        optionMenu.pack()
        
        menu = optionMenu["menu"]
        sublist1 = tk.Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='list 1', menu=sublist1)
        sublist1.add_command(label="option1")
        
        sublist2 = tk.Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='list 2', menu=sublist2)
        sublist2.add_command(label="option2")
        
        
root = tk.Tk()
app =Windows(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to add another nested `dropdown` list when I click on `option1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another menu for "option 1", like you create one for "list 1":

```py
class Windows:
   def __init__(self,master):
        var = tk.StringVar()
        optionMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(master,var,'Default')
        optionMenu.pack()

        menu = optionMenu["menu"]
        sublist1 = tk.Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='list 1', menu=sublist1)

        # menu for "option 1"
        option1 = tk.Menu(sublist1, tearoff=0)
        option1.add_command(label="value 1")
        option1.add_command(label="value 2")
        sublist1.add_cascade(label='option 1', menu=option1)

        sublist2 = tk.Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='list 2', menu=sublist2)
        sublist2.add_command(label="option2")
```